# Using maps on api 21+ inside of tab

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am just working on an application trying to learn a lot of the newer technology with API 21 / API 22. I am relatively new to android In general, but just want to make sure I am doing everything the up to date way. In my app I have a `SlidingTabLayout` which there are 2 main tabs. In one tab I have a `listView` and in the other tab I was wanting a map. Previously I had the map working in its own separate activity and it worked fine, but that was set up like `public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity`.

The xml was as:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

I was doing this based on the google maps example in android studio. Since the `slidingTabLayout` accepts fragments, I couldn't use the MapsActivity because it extended `FragmentActivity`. So I found a way around it by using `MapView` which extended `fragment` and in the xml it looks like:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I am just wondering because I don't know much about the Maps api if using `MapView` is ok in current times, or if there is a better new way to do this? Are there drawbacks to using `MapView` vs `MapFragment`?

Comment: What is `<xmlns:android[...]`?

Comment: Woops sorry. Updated op

Comment: I don't understand: is there a `NavigationView` AND a `SlidingTabLayout`? Also, prefer `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to `FragmentPagerAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a `FragmentActivity` (or `AppCompatActivity`), and keep using your `Fragment`:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

I don't see the usage of `MapView` anymore, nor in the official guides as of now.

**You should use `SupportMapFragment`.**

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Comment: Okay. As far as using a `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity` inside of a tab that is expecting a class extending fragment, what would be the best way in tackling that? Any tips? I only used the `MapView` because I couldn't get the original stuff to work.

Comment: "`Activity` inside a tab"? I never said that. Your `Activity` should contains a `SlidingTabLayout` and a `<fragment ... android:name= com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`. Please define better what "original stuff don't work"... And post more code of the "stuff that didn't work".

Comment: I updated op with a bit more info. Thanks for the help

Comment: Okay, couldn't you use a plain `Fragment` (add it to your `Adapter`) and inside it have only a `SupportMapFragment`?

Comment: Thanks, don't worry about the other stuff. I just needed to know if MapView was worth it or not